# SwiftUI NavigationStack animation problem when navigating back to parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a parent view with a `NavigationStack` containing a List with `NavigationLinks`, the `NavigationStack` have a large title.

These NavLinks go to an other `List` with `Sections` in it, this `List` have a inline title.

The problem appears when going back to the parent view, the `NavigationStack's` title is rendered as `.inline` for half a second and then go back to the `.large` title place.

Here's my parent view :

```
struct TeamsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChildView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Test")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title 1")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}
```

The child view :

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
         List {
              Section {
                  //...
              }
              Section {
                  //...
              }
         }
         .navigationTitle("Title 2")
         .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
     }
}
```

And here is a GIF of the animation problem :

[image: Title animation problem when going back to parent view]

I've made some tests with differents simulator devices, real device, to change where the `.navigationTitle` is applied in both parent and child view, to remove the NavStack from the child view... and I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the additional `NavigationStack` within `ChildView`. Its inclusion causes a new navigation bar to be created as you push, and destroyed as you go back, so the SwiftUI drawing system doesn't correctly link the back button to the title in the parent view.

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                //...
            }
            Section {
                //...
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Title 2")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

This means that the preview for ChildView will look odd as by default it no longer sits in its own navigation stack. You can remedy that by adding a stack into your preview code. For example:

```swift
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      ChildView()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I already tried without the `NavigationStack` in the `ChildView` but it doesn't change anything, I still have the animation problem

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `NavigationStack` to a `NavigationView` in the parent view resolved my issue, I can't understand why but it worked.

Parent view :

```
struct TeamsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChildView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Test")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title 1")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
}
```

Child view :

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("test")
            }
            Section {
                Text("test2")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Title2")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: NavigationView is deprecated, you shouldn't accept an answer to your question that is deprecated as of the writing of the answer.